# ¿como solucionar problemas de rendimiento por el cache?

Tags: html, cache

Resulta que subi un sistema a un servidor , y es bastante lento , sospecho que es por el cache ya que me envia este error :

[image: Error cache]

En mi head tengo el siguiente código :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <title>Inicio</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/main.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../assets/img/favicon.png" type="image/x-icon">

</head>
```

(Editado)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135244/discussion-on-question-by-luis-cifuentes-como-solucionar-problemas-de-rendimien).